# Hadoop 3rd Party Library Dependencies on Local Files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

So I'm working on a hadoop project that makes extensive use of some 3rd party libraries that rely on the availability of small local files.  A lot of them are config files, although one of them is a 34MB dictionary file. Essentially, I am trying to wrap the library to operate on much larger inputs and outputs.  The particular libraries in question are [s-match](http://www.semanticmatching.org) and [WordNet JWNL](http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/).

What is the correct way to make sure these smaller files are available to the mapper and reducer nodes locally at runtime?

The alternative is to extensively alter the 3rd party libraries, which I'd obviously rather avoid.  Surely there's got to be a way to package and propagate these files to the local filesystems, avoiding the need for MR jobs to read exclusively from the HDFS and/or special objects.

Answer (score 0):

The most standard way to do it is to add these files to Hadoop's [distributed cache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html). [Here's an article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/) on how the distributed cache works. Basically, if you are using the vanilla hadoop API, you can add files to the distributed cache via your JobConf.

```
 JobConf job = new JobConf();
 DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("myfile.txt"),job);
```

If you are using an uberjar to run your job, you can also just ship them in the classpath of the uberjar, but this is a bit dirtier and will blow up the size of your jar file.